# Active directory GUID

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

how can convert   IADs ::get_GUID(BSTR * ) thar return bstr valur to GUID data type  that have ( -  ) in GUID

Comment: Please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [UuidFromString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379336%28VS.85%29.aspx).